# Chrome extension - Notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

How I can send a notification for everyone that has installed my extension?

I'm using `new Notification(...)` but the notification is just sending for me.

Thank you for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this requires a lot of work already done in the extension to be able to do that *without* updating the extension.

For instance, your extension can periodically look for new notices on your website.

If you need more urgency, you either need to keep WebSocket connections to your server or use some manner of push services, like `gcm` API that Max Worg [just mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28148683/934239).

That said, to use all this you need to have the support *already in place* in your extension.

---

Okay, but suppose you don't have that support, or don't need it that often.

The usual way to do it is with an extension update, where you add a message for the users and increment a variable with the "release notes" version, so that it will only be shown once. A good idea is to use [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for this, so that the user won't be annoyed multiple times.

```js
var message = "Sup user, check this out!";
var message_version = 4; // Update this when you want to show a new one

chrome.storage.sync.get(
  {message_version: 0}, // Provide default
  function(data) {
    if(data.message_version < message_version) {
      notify(message); // TODO: implement notify()
      // Alternatively, open a page with the notice with chrome.tabs.create()
      chrome.storage.sync.set({message_version: message_version});
    }
  }
);
```

You can see a real-life example [here](https://github.com/knyar/theoldreader-chrome/blob/c1d7fc3a8444f8733076eecadcaaeb5bebde754f/source/js/functions.js#L212) (using a hybrid of `localStorage` and `chrome.storage`).

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the new [gcm](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) service for Push Notifications via [Google Cloud Messaging Service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/).

[Here is a tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cloudMessaging) on Google's Chrome Developer page.